# Prerequisite before obfuscating Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, obfuscation, deobfuscation

I tried different obfuscation tools for JavaScript, but when I use resultant it does not work.

I removed all comments, single-line and multi-line comments, and beautified the code in order to have proper semi-colon and proper formatting.

My question is : **What are the prerequisites before obfuscating the code?**

Comment: make sure your syntax is perfect. if you load it in IE, it'll fail if it's not. other browsers work still sometimes. things like trailing commas, missing semicolons, etc are technically in-valid (and will fail in IE) and will fail when compressed because the statements are put onto a single line.

Comment: To extend on what @Derek said, trailing commas are valid as of ES5 - ancient browsers prior to ES5 spec (such as IE7 and below) will error with trailing commas. Not sure what you meant with missing semicolons being an error - ASI is a strong aspect of the language. Some things such as multi-line return may generate errors though.

Comment: be sure to use Lint/Hint, avoid eval() and Function(), and be careful about using tricks like function.name...

Comment: @FabrícioMatté a bunch of the obfuscaters crap out with missing semicolons. Why? because they just remove line breaks and BOOM, you have a bug.

Comment: @epascarello I see. I'd expect a modern compiler/obfuscator to correct missing semicolons before concatenating everything but I guess you're right.

Comment: _"What are the prerequisites before obfuscating the code?"_ - (1) Come up with a good reason to obfuscate. I can't think of any. Minify, yes. Obfuscate for the sake of obfuscating? Nah.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: if the compiler/obfuscator actually parses the code, then it should perform ASI anyway - that is independent of the actual code and can be done without actually running the previous code.

Answer (score 0):

If your code doesn't have any errors or warnings when debugging, then it should obfuscate. Read more about the tool you're using to make sure it supports your JavaScript implementation.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure that your code runs inside an Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (see below example)
- Do not rely on global variables (or explicitly pass them in as below for $)
- Use the passed in object to create any globally exposed objects/methods (window.somename = {})
- Use event binding, not on* attributes in your html markup.

If your code can run in relative isolation as below, it should be able to obfuscate very well...

**Example:**

```
(function(window, $){
  //your code here

  //create global namespace - expose classes/methods
  window.MyProject = {
    someMethod: someInternalMethodToExpose
    SomeClassName: SomeClass
  };

  //internal stuff
  function someInternalMethodToExpose() {
    ...
  }

  //constructor function
  function SomeClass() {
    ...
  }
  SomeClass.prototype.someMethod = function() {
    ...
  }
}(window || this, jQuery));
```

Comment: The problem is that I have create a HTML5 app, using jQuery, joHTML and my own made some javascript classes. I have it in a single file some.js. Its working without obfuscate when I obfuscate it, its not worked. I think I have to code it in pure javascript!

Comment: If you follow a typical amd pattern, you *should* be able to obfuscate... for that matter, if you have *ALL* your required JS, including jQuery in a single file, you can probably use the google closure compiler to do a heavily optimized version, which should be obfuscation enough.